# Is it possible to run a tasklist from within an Ansible module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-collections

I am developing a collection containing a number of playbooks for complex system configurations. However, I'd like to simplify the usage of them to a single module plugin, named 'install'. In the Python code of the module will be decided what playbook will be called to perform the actual task. Say

```
- name: Some playbook written by the end user
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    ...
    - install:
        name: docker
        version: latest
        state: present
    ...
```

Based on the specified **name**, **version** and **state** will the Python code of the **install** module invoke programmatically the adequate playbook(s) to perform the installation of the latest release of Docker. These playbooks are also included into the collection.

If task lists are a better fit than playbooks, then task lists it is.

In fact, I don't mind the precise implementation. For as long as:

1. Everything is packed into a collection
2. The end user does it all with one 'install' task as depicted above

Is that even possible ?

Comment: The playbooks can't be nested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible. For example, given the variable in a file

```yaml
shell> cat foo_bar_install.yml
foo_bar_install:
  name: docker
  version: latest
  state: present
```

Create the playbooks in the collection *foo.bar*

```
shell> tree collections/ansible_collections/foo/bar/
collections/ansible_collections/foo/bar/
├── galaxy.yml
└── playbooks
    ├── install_docker.yml
    └── install.yml

1 directory, 3 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat collections/ansible_collections/foo/bar/playbooks/install_docker.yml
- name: Install docker
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          Playbook foo.bar.install_docker.yml
          version: {{ version|d('UNDEF') }}
          state: {{ state|d('UNDEF') }}
```

```yaml
shell> cat collections/ansible_collections/foo/bar/playbooks/install.yml 
- import_playbook: "foo.bar.install_{{ foo_bar_install.name }}.yml"
  vars:
    version: "{{ foo_bar_install.version }}"
    state: "{{ foo_bar_install.state }}"
```

Given the inventory

```
shell> cat hosts 
host1
host2
```

Run the playbook *foo.bar.install.yml* and provide the extra variables in the file *foo_bar_install.yml*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook foo.bar.install.yml -e @foo_bar_install.yml

PLAY [Install docker] ************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    Playbook foo.bar.install_docker.yml
    version: latest
    state: present
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: |-
    Playbook foo.bar.install_docker.yml
    version: latest
    state: present

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I meant the module foo.bar.install to be a Python module. So I need programmatically from there to call a tasklist or playbook. The final result should be one simple install task in a playbook, which calls the Python module, which runs the specialized task list or playbook.

Comment: A task can't call a playbook. Instead of a hypothetical *foo.bar.install* module, which must be used in a playbook anyway, run the *foo.bar.install* playbook. If this doesn't solve the use case  [edit] the question and make the case [mre].